# bash and awk extract string at specific position in non-utf file

Tags: linux, bash, awk, encoding, iconv

I've a file `foo.txt` that is encoded with `chatset ISO-8859-1`.
I am doing some field extraction with `awk`, based in a specific position.
e.g *at each line, extract a string that starts in pos 10 with length 5.*

That is a simple task, however the below command has **different behaviors in different Linux Machines** (with different bash/awk versions).

In **Machine 1 OK**, Machine 2 NOT ok:

`cat foo.dat | iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8 | awk '{print substr($0, 10,5)}' > results.utf8`

In Machine 1 NOT ok, **Machine 2 OK**:

`cat foo.dat | awk '{print substr($0, 10,5)}' | iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8 > results.utf8`

If I run the same command with the same input file, the results are different on each line that contains a "non-utf" char like (a▒c) before the 'cut' position".

No idea where the issue is, linux Kernel, bash or awk version... and specially how to have a common way to extract the desired strings...

Comment: (bit of a guess): awk doesn't support encodings; so substr($0, 10, 5) refers to bytes.  When you convert it, a byte >= 0x80 will be converted into two bytes, so awk will select a different subset.   If you really need one, the awk from plan9 supports utf-8, iirc.

Comment: probably just need to (re)set your locale; here's an [example of extracting 1st N utf8 characters from a string](https://superuser.com/a/1661906) ... (for N==3) using `LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8` the `awk` script works as desired (ie, output == 3x 2-byte characters) but if `LC_CTYPE=C` is used then the `awk` script outputs garbage (ie, output == 3 bytes)

Comment: nice hint. I get also different outputs in Machine 1 and 2 with the cmd: `printf 'áéíóú' | LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 awk '{print substr($0,1,3);exit}'`

Answer (score 2):

> No idea where the issue is, linux Kernel, bash or awk version...

[The GNU Awk User's Guide - Bytes vs. Characters](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Bytes-vs_002e-Characters.html) claims that

> The POSIX standard requires that `awk` function in terms of characters,
> not bytes. Thus in `gawk`, `length()`, `substr()`, `split()`,
> `match()` and the other string functions (...) all work in terms of
> characters in the local character set, and not in terms of bytes. (Not
> all `awk` implementations do so, though).

If above hold true then answer *how to have a common way to extract the desired strings* is to use `AWK` implementation compliant with POSIX (or at least who respect above rule to work in terms of characters, not bytes) and to make sure local character set is as desired.

Comment: hum.. that helps. Better to check first the `awk` version. Thanks for the hint

Comment: I see, in one machine there is `gawk`, in another `mawk`.  In man page for both versions, it says"  conforms  to the POSIX 1003.1 (gawk)  1003.2 (mawk) " :/

Comment: @Alg_D if you've got the option I'd suggest installing/using the same version of `awk` in both machines (my preference would be `gawk`)

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use a language which only has one implementation and where you can turn off UTF-8 (or rather, fail to turn it on).

It's not entirely clear what you expect the output to be, but I'm guessing you want something like this:

```
perl -lne 'print substr($_, 9, 5)' foo.dat | iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8
```

Notice how the conversion only happens after the extraction, so you can be sure that each byte is exactly one character.